# How to get Excel VBA macro to manipulate data on multiple spreadsheets?

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way for me to get the logic in an Excel Macro (or add-in) to pull and manipulate data from multiple spreadsheets?

Something along the lines of: For each row in Spreadsheet A(If site URL in Spreadsheet A = Site URL in Spreadsheet B, then copy value "Spreadsheet B Column X" into Spreadsheet A Column Y).

Comment: there is definitely ways to do this in `vba`.  What have you tried so far and what isn't working?

Comment: Vlookup, Index & Match, Lookup.... no need for silly vba

Comment: Did you try Googling it?

Comment: @HoldenCaulfield Lookup `VLOOKUP`.  Lots of links I could give you on that.  [Microsoft Link with some vids](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/VLOOKUP-What-it-is-and-when-to-use-it-5984e27b-4f0d-431e-83b1-7ab062c75493) [techonthenet](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/vlookup.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There sure is. This is done using the `sheets()` command to switch between sheets. You can either use indexes (they start at 1) or if you have named sheets you can type in the name as a string `sheets("reports").activate`

This code will do the comparison for you. We assume sheet `A` is `Sheets(1)` and sheet `B` is assumed to be `sheets(2)`, We are only comparing column `A` from both sheets

```
Sub test()
    col_2_search = "A"
    LastRowA = Sheets(1).Cells(Sheets(1).Rows.Count, col_2_search ).End(xlUp).Row

    For curr_row = 1 To LastRowA
        val_from_a = Sheets(1).Cells(curr_row, col_2_search ).Value
        val_from_b = Sheets(2).Cells(curr_row, col_2_search ).Value

        If (val_from_a = val_from_b) Then
            'this should be where you put your copy paste code
            MsgBox ("match row " & curr_row & " value:" & val_from_a)
        End If

    Next
End Sub
```

**Edit**

An alternative solution for using match. There may be a cleaner way to write this, but I just threw it up really quickly

```
Sub test()
    col_2_search = "A"
    LastRowA = Sheets(1).Cells(Sheets(1).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LastRowB = Sheets(2).Cells(Sheets(2).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For curr_row = 1 To LastRowA
        value_from_A = Sheets(1).Cells(curr_row, col_2_search ).Value

        'we are searching B from column 1 to the last populated column in b
        Var = Application.Match(value_from_A, Range(Sheets(2).Cells(1, col_2_search ), Sheets(2).Cells(LastRowB, col_2_search )))

        'if there wasn't an error, var contains the row of range B that matches
        'a
        If Not (IsError(Var)) Then
            MsgBox ("Row " & curr_row & " of A matches row " & Var & " of B, both contain: " & value_from_A)
        End If

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Note that this only compares row to row.  While vlookup or index & match would compare a value against the entire column.

Comment: Thanks @chancea. I do need it to compare 1 value against an entire column of values.

Comment: @andrew I'm new to VBA how do I modify your code to add Index/Match?

Comment: @HoldenCaulfield Index/Match is not VBA its a formula

Comment: @chancea is correct again, but even though its not a native VBA function you can still use it if you call it properly  using `Application.WorksheetFunction` (or in this case `Application.` seems to work too) using worksheet functions can be pretty buggy and it would probably be better to simply embed code into the cells. In any even I made an edit to my answer